# How do I get absolute path from using find unix command

Tags: shell-script, find, filenames

How to get absolute path by using find command.
actually I am running the following script:-

```
find . -size +20M | while read a
do
     i=$(echo $a | sed 's:/: :g')
     echo $a;
     j=($i)
     fileName=${j[${#j[@]}-1]}
     userName=${j[${#j[@]}-3]}
done
```

but here variable `$a` showing path starting from `./Downloads/filename` but I want absolute path from `/`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use find with an absolute path.

```
find /path/ -size +20M
```

It will print the whole path.
If you do not know the working directory then use command substitution for `pwd` like this:

```
find "`pwd`" -size +20M 
   #or like this:
find "$(pwd)" -size +20M
```

To get your working directory

Anyway, it seems that Bash man now advise to use `$()` over ``` `` ``` so you should use the second form. You can also probably refer directly to the `$PWD` variable that contains the working directory of your script and it would be probably faster if you have to use in a loop.

```
find "$PWD" -size +20M
```

Comment: But i donot have path, I only have . as current directory then?

Comment: Don't start with `.`, use `$(pwd)` instead, that will give you a full path.

Comment: The command substition `$(pwd)` won't work if the path contains a newline. Instead, you can just use the paramater expansion `$PWD`

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `pwd` command or print out the file `realpath`:

```
$ find "$(pwd)" -size +20M
$ find . -size +20M -exec realpath {} +
```

Both commands real give you the absolute path to the files.

Comment: But 2nd one is giving **find: `realpath': No such file or directory**

Comment: Hum. Maybe you don't have it installed although it is provided by the `coreutils` package. Try to locate it with `which realpath`.

Comment: It is locating nothing..

Comment: Which system are you using?

Comment: Linux BANE 3.7-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.7.2-0+kali8 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Well it looks like Kali Linux is providing a `realpath` package. Other than that, I cannot help you more.

Comment: @Devavrata, `realpath` is in a a separate package in Debian.

Comment: `readlink -f` is another possibility, and AFAIK it is more common than realpath.

Comment: or `find . -size +20M | xargs realpath`.

Answer (score 0):

To List all PNG and JPEG files which are 7 days old with absolute path.

```
$ find $PWD/ -mtime -7 -print -exec grep -e ".png\|.jpg" {} \;
```

Here `$PWD` will be added to every file matched.