# Fix File Path Casing

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, find

I have a list of stored file paths ie (`impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/util/collections/multimaps.java`).  The paths were coverted to lowercase prior to storing.

Now, I need to access the file in a bash script.  Is there a simple command to "fix" the casing and find the file?  For simplicity, assume that there are not multiple versions of the file with different cases.  Note also, that the directories in the path may need to have their casing fixed.

I've thought about using find, but you can't have a full path so from the root `find . -iname multimaps.java` might return multiple files only one of which is in the correct directory structure.

I need the corrected path to end up in a variable in a bash script.

Comment: to get full path from find you could use this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/how-do-i-get-absolute-path-from-using-find-unix-command/125781#125781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU `find` has a `-iwholename` predicate which solves my problem:

```
find . -iwholename ./impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/util/collections/multimaps.java
```

To get it in a variable:

```
cased=`find . -iwholename "$filepath"`
```

Comment: Note from a performance point of view that it scans the whole directory tree to find that file (while for instance it wouldn't need to descend into `./impl/obj/` or `./whatever`).

Comment: Would the most performant option in bash be splitting on the slashes and looping over the files yourself?  Since the directories are likely lowercase on the actual system, looping on most of the contents probably wouldn't be necessary, it could just check if the directory exists and jump into it.  That would be a much more complicated set of code though?

Comment: Getting the results into a variable is the part which *really* sucks.  You can probably use `find` with `-exec` to execute (even a complex) command on each match.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
files=((#i)${(f)^"$(<file.list)"}(N))
printf '%s\n' $files
```

(where `file.list` is the file containing that list of paths in lower case, one per line).

- `(#i)`: case insensitive glob (needs `extendedglob`)
- `${(f)"$expansion"}`: split the expansion on line feeds (newline)
- `${^array}`: do brace-expansion type of expansion for the array.
- `(N)`: nullglob glob qualifier (remove globs that don't match).

For a single file, it's just:

```
setopt extendedglob
file=impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/util/collections/multimaps.java
matches=((#i)$file)
```

(here omitting the `(N)` so you do get an error if there's no match)

The `ksh93` equivalent would be:

```
matches=(~(iN)"$file") # N for nullglob, otherwise the glob expands to itself
                       # instead of giving an error when it doesn't match.
```

`bash` has a `nocaseglob` option to match case-insensitively. However

```
matches=($file)
```

won't work. You'd need to *activate* globbing (by using any of the glob operators) for each path component like in

```
shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob
matches=([i]mpl/[s]rc/[m]ain/[j]ava/[o]rg/[j]boss/[w]eld/[u]til/[c]ollections/[m]ultimaps.java)
```

With any shell with support for a `[...]` glob operator (so in essence, all but `fish`), you could also rewrite the glob as `[iI][mM][pP][lL]/[sS][rR]...` and so on.

Note that it's different from a `find . -ipath "./$file"` in that the shell doesn't need to crawl the whole directory tree. It first reads the current directory to find directories (or symlinks to directories! Another difference from `find`) called `impl` or `Impl` or `ImPl`, etc. then only reads the content of those directories to find some `src`/`SRC`/`srC` etc. and so on.

Another difference is that it still works properly if the paths components happen to contain glob operators (like `impl/***src***/whatever`).

Comment: I don't currently have zsh installed, though I could potentially install it.  Does this avoid looping over the whole file tree?

Comment: No looping involved, Loren -- but you would have to have your current directory set to exactly the parent of the file path(s), assuming they're relative (don't start with a `/`)

Comment: @Loren, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
shopt -s nocasematch globstar
for f in **; do for search in "${files[*]}"; do [[ $f == $search ]] && echo Found "$search" at: "$f"; done; done
```

The nocasematch shell option tells the `[[ ... == ... ]]` command to ignore case when comparing strings. The globstar shell enables the `**` brute-force bash emulation of `find`; it differs from `find` in that it will skip dot-files (unless `shopt -s dotglob` is set) and follows symlinks.

Comment: `bash`'s `**` no longer follows symlinks since 4.3

Comment: Is this any more efficient than the implementation in GNU `find`?  If I'm reading it correctly, it looks like this will also scan the whole directory tree the same as `find` (as pointed out in @Stéphane's comment).

Comment: Likely slower than find; just wanted to point out another option.

Answer (score 1):

An approach to avoid scanning the tree again and again for every file would be to list the directory tree once and then look-up the lowercase translation of the path in a hash table. For instance with:

```
NL='
'
find . -name "*$NL*" -prune -o -print | awk '
  !list_processed {paths["./" $0]; next}
  tolower($0) in paths' file.list list_processed=1 -
```

(where `file.list` contains the list of lowercase files, one per line).

We're skipping the files (and not descending into directories) with newlines in their names as they can't possibly be stored in the `file.list` if that list is newline delimited (and would break that post-processing).

Note however that that skipping won't work if file names also contain invalid characters. See the *byte vs character* section at [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](/a/321757) for more details.